# Why is "ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate" not called on sign in?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-sign-in

I've added code to support Sign in with Apple. The code works fine, but the callback delegate function is not called when TouchID succeeds on a real device (iPhone 7 Plus).

What should I check to fix this?

Comment: Fixed grammar and language usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
Do write delegate function to public methods.