# Apple SignIn not calling ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate for certain phones

Tags: ios, swift, apple-sign-in

I have an odd situation.  I have implemented Apple Sign In within my iOS Swift app (minimum iOS version target is 13.0) and it works correctly on my iPhone 11 (running iOS 13.7).  However, when I run the same app on an iPhone 7 (running iOS 13.6), the AsAuthoriztionControllerDelegate function is not called.  The code looks like this:

```swift
@objc func signinWithAppleTap(_ sender: Any) {
    let requests = [ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider().createRequest(), ASAuthorizationPasswordProvider().createRequest()]
        
    let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: requests)
    authorizationController.delegate = self
    authorizationController.presentationContextProvider = self
    authorizationController.performRequests()
}
```

The ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate implementation looks like this:

```swift
extension LoginViewController: ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate {
    func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization) {
        switch authorization.credential {
            case let appleIDCredential as ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential:
               ... some code
        }
    }
}
```

The *authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization)* function is never called.  I did take a look at: [Why is "ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate" not called on sign in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58907137/why-is-asauthorizationcontrollerdelegate-not-called-on-sign-in) but there was no enlightenment there.

Thoughts on why I am seeing such divergent functionality on different phones but essentially the same iOS OS level?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I posted too soon.  The issue is that on my iPhone 11, both flows (New Login and Existing Login) flows worked with my existing code but I actually need to break it out to work correctly:

```swift
@objc func signinWithAppleTap(_ sender: Any) {
    // saved the AppleUser id into KeyChain upon initial login
    if KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "Foo-AppleUser") != nil {
        // this is the existing user, resigning in
        let requests = [ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider().createRequest(), ASAuthorizationPasswordProvider().createRequest()]
        
        let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: requests)
        authorizationController.delegate = self
        authorizationController.presentationContextProvider = self
        authorizationController.performRequests()
    }
    else {
        // this is a new user login flow
        let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
        let request = appleIDProvider.createRequest()
        request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
                
        let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
        authorizationController.delegate = self
        authorizationController.presentationContextProvider = self
        authorizationController.performRequests()
    }
}
```